# Close Dropdown when other Dropdown is toggled active

Tags: javascript, class, dropdown

i am trying to close let´s say Dropdown A automatically, when Dropdown B gets `classList.toggle("active)` (in this case i toggle the ClassList with a Click)

I can open (`classList.toggle("active)`) and close (`classList.toggle("inactive)`) it manually, but i want to close it automatically.

Right now i got this:

```
function dropdown() {

    let employerBranding = document.querySelector(".employer-branding");
    let marketing = document.querySelector(".marketing");
    let corporateOverall = document.querySelector(".corporate-overall");
    let technicalData = document.querySelector(".technical-data");

    let categoryModules = [employerBranding, marketing, corporateOverall, technicalData];
    let categoryDropdown = $(".category-dropdown");


    for (let i = 0; i < categoryModules.length; i++) {

        categoryModules[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            categoryDropdown.slideDown();
        });

    }

}

dropdown();
```

The Problem is now: when i click on one of the 4 Modules of course it opens all of the Dropdowns.
How can i trigger the correct Dropdown to the correct Module, so only one (the one below the clicked Module) opens up
&&
How can i add with another `click` a `.slideUp()` to slide it up again?

Comment: Do you want it to be like an accordion thing?

Comment: Hmm no i just want if one Dropdown  gets activated with a click, the other Dropdown which got activated before with a click to close itself.
The Dropdowns are closed at first. Dropdown A opens up (when you clicking on it) --> all Good
You open up Dropdown B --> Dropdown A closes & Dropdown B opens up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little while a came up with this solution

```
function closeDropdown() {

    // let employerBrandingDropdown = document.querySelector(".employer-branding-dropdown");
    let employerBrandingDropdown = $('.employer-branding-dropdown');
    let marketingDropdown = $(".marketing-dropdown");
    let corporateOverallDropdown = $(".corporate-overall-dropdown");
    let technicalDataDropdown = $(".technical-data-dropdown");

    let dropdownArray = [employerBrandingDropdown, marketingDropdown, corporateOverallDropdown, technicalDataDropdown];

    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (event) {
        for (let i = 0; i < dropdownArray.length; i++) {
            let categoryDropdown = dropdownArray[i];
            if ($(event.target !== categoryDropdown) && $(event.target).parent() !== categoryDropdown) {
                $(categoryDropdown).stop().slideUp();
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very basic example of what you want to achieve:

```js
const one = document.querySelector('#one');
const two = document.querySelector('#two');

const toggle = (e) => {
    if (e.target.id === 'one') {
        one.classList.toggle('active');
        two.classList.remove('active');
    } else {
        two.classList.toggle('active');
        one.classList.remove('active');
    }
}

one.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggle(e));
two.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggle(e));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      div {
        display: inline;
        margin: 20px;
        padding: 100px;
        background-color: #444;
      }
      .active {
        padding: 200px 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Generally (and especially if creating more dropdowns), I would suggest a more sophisticated approach involving looping through all of them, such as Rounin mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a dropdown is activated with a click:

1. Close all the dropdowns (ie. loop through the dropdowns and set each to `.inactive`)
2. Open the activated dropdown